# How to change this Paredit configuration on the init file from the classic imperative installation to a declarative approach via use-package?

Tags: package, hooks, use-package, autoload, paredit

When I first installed [Paredit](https://github.com/emacsmirror/paredit), I used to install things via the classic `M-x` and `package-install`. Then, I inserted the following configuration:

```lisp
(autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook       #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook             #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook             #'enable-paredit-mode) ;isso é para CL
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode) ;ativado via M-x
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook           #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode) ;ativar o paredit no slime
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'clojurescript-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)

;; Paredit Keybinding configuration
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C->") 'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-<") 'paredit-forward-barf-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M-<") 'paredit-backward-slurp-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M->") 'paredit-backward-barf-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") nil)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") nil)))
```

This used to work out. Now, I have moved to a new machine and I have not used classic installation yet (`M-x` and `package-install`).

I want to do everything via [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

I am especially unsure about how to handle the `auto-load` expression.

This is my first draft/attempt. I did **not** solve the `auto-load` part, but things seem to work well (I could be missing something, though):

```lisp
(use-package paredit
  :ensure t
  :hook ((emacs-lisp-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (eval-expression-minibuffer-setup . enable-paredit-mode)
         (ielm-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (lisp-mode . enable-paredit-mode) 
         (lisp-interaction-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (scheme-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (slime-repl-mode . enable-paredit-mode) 
         (clojure-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (clojurescript-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (cider-repl-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (cider-mode . enable-paredit-mode)
         (clojure-mode . enable-paredit-mode))
  :config
  (show-paren-mode t)
    
  :bind (("C->" . paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
         ("C-<" . paredit-forward-barf-sexp)
         ("C-M-<" . paredit-backward-slurp-sexp)
         ("C-M->" . paredit-backward-barf-sexp)
         ("<C-right>" .  nil)
         ("<C-left>" .  nil)
         ("M-[" . paredit-wrap-square)
         ("M-{" . paredit-wrap-curly))
    
  ;; :after (autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on
  ;; pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
  )
```

How would you convert the declaration above to a complete `use-package` declarative installation?